# how to compare string word to chat guess?

Tags: c++

I am currently working on a program (hangman) and am having problems comparing the user input (char) to the word to be guessed (string) to determine if the guessed letter is in the word or not.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>  // ifstream and ofstream
#include <iomanip>  // input/output manipulation
#include <cctype>   // toupper() function
#include <cstring>
#include <string>   // strings
using namespace std;
#include "MyFuncts.h" // programmer defined includes

//ASCII ART FROM: http://ascii.co.uk/art/hangman by Manus O'Donnell

int main()
{
    ifstream inFile;  // used to read from the file
    string stage0;
    string stage1;
    string stage2;
    string stage3;
    string stage4;
    string stage5;
    string stage6;
    string word; // convert this to array down the road
    char guess;
    int numWrong = 0;
    bool found = true;

    //STAGE0
    stage0 = " ___________.._______\n| .__________))______|\n| | / /      ||\n| |/ /       ||\n| | /        ||\n| |/\n| |\n| |\n| |\n| |\n| |\n| |\n| |\n| |\n| |\n| |\n| |\n| |\n\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"|_        |\"\"\"|\n|\"|\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\ \       '\"|\"|\n| |        \\ \\        | |\n: :         \\ \\       : :\n. .          `'       . .\n\n\n";
    //STAGE1
    stage1 = " ___________.._______\n| .__________))______|\n| | / /      ||\n| |/ /       ||\n| | /        ||.-''.\n| |/         |/  _  \\\n| |          ||  `/,|\n| |          (\\\\`_.'\n| |\n| |\n| |\n| |\n| |\n| |\n| |\n| |\n| |\n| |\n\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"|_        |\"\"\"|\n|\"|\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\ \       '\"|\"|\n| |        \\ \\        | |\n: :         \\ \\       : :\n. .          `'       . .\n\n\n";
    //STAGE2
    stage2 = " ___________.._______\n| .__________))______|\n| | / /      ||\n| |/ /       ||\n| | /        ||.-''.\n| |/         |/  _  \\\n| |          ||  `/,|\n| |          (\\\\`_.'\n| |         .-`--'.\n| |        /Y . . Y\\\n| |          |   |\n| |          | . |\n| |          |   |\n| |\n| |\n| |\n| |\n| |\n\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"|_        |\"\"\"|\n|\"|\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\ \       '\"|\"|\n| |        \\ \\        | |\n: :         \\ \\       : :\n. .          `'       . .\n\n\n";
    //STAGE3
    stage3 = " ___________.._______\n| .__________))______|\n| | / /      ||\n| |/ /       ||\n| | /        ||.-''.\n| |/         |/  _  \\\n| |          ||  `/,|\n| |          (\\\\`_.'\n| |         .-`--'.\n| |        /Y . . Y\\\n| |       // |   |\n| |      //  | . |\n| |     ')   |   |\n| |\n| |\n| |\n| |\n| |\n\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"|_        |\"\"\"|\n|\"|\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\ \       '\"|\"|\n| |        \\ \\        | |\n: :         \\ \\       : :\n. .          `'       . .\n\n\n";
    //STAGE4
    stage4 = " ___________.._______\n| .__________))______|\n| | / /      ||\n| |/ /       ||\n| | /        ||.-''.\n| |/         |/  _  \\\n| |          ||  `/,|\n| |          (\\\\`_.'\n| |         .-`--'.\n| |        /Y . . Y\\\n| |       // |   | \\\\\n| |      //  | . |  \\\\\n| |     ')   |   |   (`\n| |\n| |\n| |\n| |\n| |\n\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"|_        |\"\"\"|\n|\"|\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\ \       '\"|\"|\n| |        \\ \\        | |\n: :         \\ \\       : :\n. .          `'       . .\n\n\n";
    //STAGE5
    stage5 = " ___________.._______\n| .__________))______|\n| | / /      ||\n| |/ /       ||\n| | /        ||.-''.\n| |/         |/  _  \\\n| |          ||  `/,|\n| |          (\\\\`_.'\n| |         .-`--'.\n| |        /Y . . Y\\\n| |       // |   | \\\\\n| |      //  | . |  \\\\\n| |     ')   |   |   (`\n| |          ||'\n| |          ||\n| |          ||\n| |          ||\n| |         / |\n\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"|_`-'     |\"\"\"|\n|\"|\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\ \       '\"|\"|\n| |        \\ \\        | |\n: :         \\ \\       : :\n. .          `'       . .\n\n\n";
    //STAGE6 - GAME OVER
    stage6 = " ___________.._______\n| .__________))______|\n| | / /      ||\n| |/ /       ||\n| | /        ||.-''.\n| |/         |/  _  \\\n| |          ||  `/,|\n| |          (\\\\`_.'\n| |         .-`--'.\n| |        /Y . . Y\\\n| |       // |   | \\\\\n| |      //  | . |  \\\\\n| |     ')   |   |   (`\n| |          ||'||\n| |          || ||\n| |          || ||\n| |          || ||\n| |         / | | \\\n\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"|_`-' `-' |\"\"\"|\n|\"|\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\ \       '\"|\"|\n| |        \\ \\        | |\n: :         \\ \\       : :\n. .          `'       . .\n\n\n";

    inFile.open("hangman.dat");
    if (!inFile)
    {
        cout << "Error opening file for reading\n";
        system("pause");
        return 1;
    }// end if
    inFile >> word; // convert these into an array as well
    while (!inFile.fail()) // .fail is better than .eof as it catches more issues
    {
        cout << "Word: " << word << endl;;
        inFile >> word;
    }
    inFile.close();

    word = caseChanger(word, true);

    //INPUT
    cout << "Word to Guess: " << word << endl << endl;

    //PROCESS & OUTPUT
    while (numWrong <= 6)
    {
        if (numWrong == 0)
            cout << stage0 << endl;
        else if (numWrong == 1)
            cout << stage1 << endl;
        else if (numWrong == 2)
            cout << stage2 << endl;
        else if (numWrong == 3)
            cout << stage3 << endl;
        else if (numWrong == 4)
            cout << stage4 << endl;
        else if (numWrong == 5)
            cout << stage5 << endl;
        else
            cout << stage6 << endl;

        cout << "Please enter a letter to guess: ";
        cin >> guess;
        guess = toupper(guess);
        cout << "You entered: " << guess << endl;

        for(int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++)
        {
            if(word[i] == guess)
                found = true;
            else
                found = false;
        }

        if (found)
        {
            cout << guess << " is in the word to guess." << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << guess << " is NOT in the word to guess." << endl;
            numWrong = numWrong++;
        }
    }

    cout << "\n\n";
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

For some reason, when I enter a letter that is part of the word, this still says it is not, and increments the number of incorrect guesses (numWrong).

Could use  afresh set of eyes, as I have no clue why this is not currently working.

Thanks!

Comment: What does `caseChanger()` do?

Comment: caseChanger is a user defined function that takes a string variable and changes the case of the ketter (if true, convery to uppercase, if false, convert to lowercase).

Comment: Please, keep your stages in an array, so you can write loop instead of 6 if elses!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in your loop to determine if the letter is correct. If it finds the correct letter, the loop doesn't end, and continues going through all the letters, which changes it back to false.

```
found = false; //Move this here to set it as false default before the loop starts
for(int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++)
    {
        if(word[i] == guess)
        {
            found = true;
            break; //Add this here to exit the loop if letter is found
        }
    }
```

Comment: Just make found = false once you done with your operation when it is true.         
        if (found)
        {
            cout << guess << " is in the word to guess." << endl;
            found = false; // Get it reset for the next loop.
        }

Answer (score 1):

Just make `found = false` once you done with your operation when it is true.

```
if (found)
{
    cout << guess << " is in the word to guess." << endl;
    found = false; // Get it reset for the next loop.
}
```